# What is the point of btrfs subvolumes?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, btrfs, bind-mount

The system administrator guide of the Btrfs wiki ([here](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SysadminGuide)) says:

> A Btrfs subvolume can be thought of as a POSIX file namespace.

I remember at first it saying that a subvolume *is*, as opposed to being able to be *thought of as*, a "POSIX file namespace". A Google search for `"POSIX file namespace"` turn up only things about Btrfs, so the phrase is unhelpful.

Just what is a subvolume in Btrfs? If a subvolume is accessible as a directory from the filesystem root, then how is mounting subvolume any different from bind mounting a directory on any other filesystem to another location without intermediately mounting the root of said filesystem? This is what I mean:

```
# standard bind mount
mkdir /mnt/data
mkdir /mnt/docs
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/data
mount --bind /mnt/data/docs /mnt/docs
umount /mnt/data
rmdir /mnt/data

# hypothetical method of directly mounting
# a file/directory on a filesystem
# to some path that achieves the same
# as the above
mkdir /mnt/docs
mount -o path_on_fs=/docs /dev/sda2 /mnt/docs

# if /docs on sda2 was a subvolume
mkdir /mnt/docs
mount -o subvol=/mnt /dev/sda2 /mnt/docs
```

What is the purpose of the subvolume feature? An example: `/var/lib/machines.raw` is a Btrfs filesystem image that is used by `systemd-machined` and `machinectl` to store virtual machines and/or containers. Presumably, Btrfs is used for subvolumes. What do the subvolumes do for that?

If a subvolume is useful for containers, does it have built-in isolation for processes running in different subvolumes?

Comment: Not sure if you can snapshot individual directories in btrfs, but you can snapshot subvolumes.

Answer (score 16):

I’m no expert—not even close!—but since I’ve been reading a lot about Btrfs lately, and since your question has gone unanswered for six months, I figured I’d give it a shot.

Here are two possible use cases. I don’t know if these are common or even *recommended* reasons for having subvolumes (like I said, not an expert), but I’ll include links to where I’ve seen them discussed to help you judge for yourself.

### Independent snapshots

A Btrfs snapshot is a copy of an entire subvolume. This could be useful in a snapshot-based recovery or backup strategy. For instance, having `/` separate from `/home` means you can roll back a system update without affecting user data; conversely, you can back up user data without keeping system files.

You can also use subvolumes to exclude directories you *don’t* want to back up. For example, if `/home` and `/home/bob/Downloads` are different subvolumes, then a snapshot of `/home` excludes bob’s downloads.

Discussion:

- [Ask Ubuntu: Btrfs subvolumes vs folders?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119014/btrfs-subvolumes-vs-folders)
- [btrfs Wiki: Incremental Backup](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Incremental_Backup)
- [openSUSE Wiki: BTRFS](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:BTRFS) Lists where the default subvolumes are, and why (pretty much always “so this data isn’t lost on rollback”)
- [r/fedora: Timeshift & BTRFS Snapshots](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/n1ekg0/timeshift_btrfs_snapshots/)
- [r/btrfs: When to use subvolumes?](https://www.reddit.com/r/btrfs/comments/8njgk6/when_to_use_subvolumes/) From the replies: “Steam games get a subvolume, because I don't want snapshots including the 10,000 mods my daughter has downloaded for her games and all their updates.”

### Different mount options

Because each subvolume is mounted individually, they can be mounted with different [mount options](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs(5)#MOUNT_OPTIONS) from one another.

Or at least, that’s the theory. In practice, it appears [only some mount options are currently supported per-subvolume](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Can_I_mount_subvolumes_with_different_mount_options.3F).

I don’t know exactly what scenarios this would enable (again: *not an expert*), but one that I just made up is setting the compression so that one subvolume is optimised for speed, while another optimises for space. Once per-subvolume `compress` is supported, of course.

Discussion:

- [unix.SE: Why are mount options not applied to subvolumes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592627/btrfs-why-are-mount-options-not-applied-to-subvolumes)
- [Phoronix: Btrfs Mount Option Benchmarks](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=btrfs-mount-linux49&num=1)
- [r/btrfs: What are optimal btrfs mount options / best practices](https://www.reddit.com/r/btrfs/comments/hiqetu/what_are_optimal_btrfs_mount_options_best/)

Comment: Another reason is quotas per subvolume.